# Can you pick the same class twice to multiclass with different archetypes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, multi-classing, archetype

Can a character multiclass into the **same** class twice and use two different archetypes in each?

For example: A character could level until the 5th level as a **'Two-handed Fighter'** *(archetype)* and then pick the 6th level as a **'Titan Fighter'** *(archetype)*, becoming a **Two-handed Fighter 5/Titan Fighter 1?**